# Count Groupby From String (array) in BigQuery

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I have this table

Schema:
name: string
interests: string

```
name  | interests
user1 | culture, travel 
user2 | soccer, studying, soccer 
user3 | tennis, science, soccer, culture
```

How to count group by interests so that it resulted with:

```
interests | count
culture   | 2
travel    | 1
soccer    | 3
... ...
```

Comment: why not normalize your table and avoid splitting the column, which is  time consuming see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a given table of string and array

```
CREATE TABLE `Dataset.ClientInterest` 
(
  ClientName string,
  Interest Array<string>
)
```

and a dataset of

```
insert into `Dataset.ClientInterest` values ('User1', [ 'culture', 'travel']),
                                               ('User2', [ 'soccer','studying','travel']),
                                               ('User3', [ 'tennis', 'science', 'soccer', 'culture' ])
```

Then unnest the array in BigQuery to allow group by

```
SELECT   interest, 
         COUNT(ClientName) 
FROM    `Dataset.ClientInterest` c, 
         UNNEST(Interest) interest 
GROUP BY interest
```

resulting in

[image: unnest array group by]